# How to Test if site is accessible from certain browser version

Tags: firefox, apache-http-server, htaccess

using rules in .htaccess I am attempting to block access to sites hosted on my server from traffic using a specific browser version (firefox 27.0).

Is there any way to test if I have .htaccess setup correctly to block visitors using this browser other than perhaps trying to locate and install this version of Firefox?

Can it be done through a php program?  through Linux command line?

Comment: Each of the major browsers allow you to customize the User-Agent string: http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Note it's easy to get around such blocks by changing the User-Agent string as per @heavyd's comment.

Comment: thanks,  i am aware that is is easy to get around,  but there is a bot clicking on my adsense ads which only uses that specific version of firefox, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Chrome extension that will allow you to imitate different user agents (including Firefox 27).

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf?hl=en-US

Follow these steps:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Copy the user-agent string in this textbox...
[image]

...reopen the extension and paste that user-agent string into this textbox; then click change.
[image]